# Cron permissions?

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, unix, cron

I have a bash script which if I run manually (as root) performs all of its tasks without issue. The tasks are just a few php scripts and then a "mv" to move the process file to a temporary folder.

The problem is, when I run the script as a cron job, I get the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat `/var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv': No such file or directory
```

That file definitely exists, so I guess it's a permissions issue, but as it's in root's crontab file I don't understand why it can't see the file. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

The script itself:

```
[root@cartman jupiter]# cat /opt/triggers/jupiter/jupiter_manager_trigger.sh 
#!/bin/bash
php /opt/triggers/jupiter/php/import.php > /var/log/triggers/jupiter_`date +%Y%m%d`_import.log
php /opt/triggers/jupiter/php/update.php > /var/log/triggers/jupiter_`date +%Y%m%d`_update.log
php /opt/triggers/jupiter/php/export.php > /var/log/triggers/jupiter_`date +%Y%m%d`_export.log
php /opt/triggers/jupiter/php/upload.php > /var/log/triggers/jupiter_`date +%Y%m%d`_upload.log
mv /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/processed/`date +%Y%m%d`_Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
```

That "mv" there appears to be the issue. However that file DEFINITELY exists:

```
[root@cartman jupiter]# ls /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/
Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
```

The import.php file also uses that file and it too can't "see" the file.

Here is the crontab for root:

```
[root@cartman jupiter]# crontab -u root -l
* * * * * cd /var/www/sugar; php -f cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
0 10 * * * sh /opt/triggers/jupiter/jupiter_manager_trigger.sh
10 4 * * * sh /opt/scripts/s3backup_www.sh
0 4 * * * sh /opt/scripts/mysql_backup.sh
```

Here is the relevant part of the import.php file:

```
$load="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv' 
INTO TABLE Managers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 5 LINES 
(Hotel,@ignore,@ignore,Title,FirstName,LastName,Email,@ignore);";
```

So it looks like the issue is still there. Mysql and mv can't "see" the file again today, although it is there:

```
Sat, 09 Mar 2013 11:00:01 +0000
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 jupiter_sftp sftpusers 9590 Mar  9 00:55 Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jupiter_sftp sftpusers 9590 Mar  9 00:55 /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
```

Here are the errors from the logs:

```
Data base error. MySQL writes: Can't get stat of '/var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv' (Errcode: 2)

mv /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/processed/20130310_Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
```

mv: cannot stat `/var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv': No such file or directory

I'm almost certain it's a permissions issue. The cron "root" can't seem to "see" those files, but if I move them as root, or run the script as su root, then the script completes correctly.

Comment: If it was a permissions error, you'd get an "Permission denied" error, not a "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 2):

*No such file or directory* is a clear message that the file isn't found.
A permission problem would give one of the following messages:

- *Operation not permitted*
- *Permission denied*

<strike>So please double check your situation and maybe provide more informations, e.g. the relevant source code and crontab entry.</strike>

A good idea for debugging your situation is to enrich the `jupiter_manager_trigger.sh` with the following debug code.

```
{ date -R
  set -xv
  ls -l /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/
  ls -l /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
  mv /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/incoming/Yesterday_email_addrs.csv /var/sftp/jupiter_sftp/processed/`date +%Y%m%d`_Yesterday_email_addrs.csv
  set +xv
} >>/tmp/debug_jupiter.out
```

On this way you ensure that at the invocation time the file is existing and in what state it is.

Comment: Updated the original post with further details

Comment: Please try the approach above to debug your situation.

Comment: So what was the problem ? Don't forget to close the question.

Comment: Well, I don't know for certain yet as I reduced the cron job to just your suggested debug command. I'll setup a proper full test (with the php tasks) and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I think it's all working now - not sure how, but your debug code seems to have fixed it, so I'm keeping it! Thanks for all your help! :)